# Problem of fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

I have to prove if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in all the points. And $a,b$ are fixed points with $a<b$ such that $\vert f'(a) \vert <1$ and $\vert f'(b) \vert <1$ then exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$.

I defined $g(x)=f(x)-x$ then $g(a)=0$ and $g(b)=0$ and by the Rolle's Theorem exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $g'(c)=0$ so $f'(c)=1$ and $\vert f'(c) \vert =1$ and I don't know how to use the other hypothesis

Answer (score 2):

As OP did, define $g(x) = f(x) - x$. Then we have that $g'(a) < 0$ and $g'(b) < 0$.

Take $a'$ slightly larger than $a$ s.t. $g(a') < 0$, and take $b'$ slightly less than $b$ s.t. $g(b') > 0$ and s.t. $a' < b'$.

Then by the IVT, there is some $c \in (a', b') \subseteq (a, b)$ s.t. $g(c) = 0$.

Comment: +1. Nice proof!

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate more why $\exists b'$ s.t. $g(b') > 0$? If take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, then derivative is negative for $x>0$, so does interval $(3,5)$ giving counterexample?  @Kavi Rama Murthy.

Comment: @zkutch As $t \to 0+$ we have $\frac {g(b)-g(b-t)} t \to g'(b) <0$ and $g(b)=0$. So $g(b-t)>0$ for all $t$ sufficiently small.

Comment: And why $g(b)=0$? @Kavi Rama Murthy.

Comment: @zkutch Read the question fully. It says $a$ and $b$ are fixed points of $f$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy. Look please - there is simply "fixed points with $a<b$", not "fixed points of $f$" as you wrote. This is why I brought counterexample.

Comment: @zkutch OK, there are two ways of reading the question. But there are obvious counter-examples with your interpretation so I would still think that  Doctor Who's  interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy. Since the tag "fixed-points" is indicated, you can probably interpret the word "fixed" in the first two lines as "fixed points of $f$". In this case, I agree with your estimation of proof. But for formal accuracy, imho, should be advised OP to write this clearly, which will give unambiguous reading. Same gives if Doctor Who emphasize this in his proof.